# Launch ContextMenu when 'back' key is hit?

Tags: android, contextmenu, back-button

I need to override the back button to launch a context menu.

I have

```
    @Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event)
{
    switch (keyCode)
    {
    case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK :

        return true;
    }

    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}


        @Override  
    public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v,ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {  
 super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, v, menuInfo);  
     menu.setHeaderTitle("Quit");  
     menu.add(0, v.getId(), 0, "Yes");   
     menu.add(0, v.getId(), 0, "No");   

 }  
    @Override  
    public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {  
            if(item.getTitle()=="Yes"){quit(0);}
            if(item.getTitle()=="No"){quit(1);}
        else {return false;}  
    return true;  
    }
```

How can I call the ContextMenu from within 'case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK :'?

Comment: http://commonsware.com/blog/2011/07/21/back-means-back.html

Comment: @CommonsWare: I don't think it's particularly polite to rant about someone like that.

Comment: Yes, I understand that though my users are not going to be pleased if they hit the back button and it ends mid session. I am using this to ask for a confirmation of whether or not the user wants to revert back to the main menu.

Comment: In general, but especially on mobile, "Are you sure?" dialogs (note: dialog, not context menu) are annoying. Apps that have this kind of needless interruption just feel wrong. I pressed Back, so take me back. If I had some unsaved changes, save them automatically for me.. but just take me back.

Comment: I agree with @Christopher, automatically save the data on exit. Pop up confirmation dialogs are annoying.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [openContextMenu](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#openContextMenu%28android.view.View%29): you'll need to pass in the View you want to have the context menu opened, but that should work.

Comment: Thanks - I've never come across passing a view manually, I usually see it being passed as 'View v' in methods like 'onCreateContextMenu'. How do do I define/reference my current view? Thank you

Comment: Well, a context menu is for a specific view: usually it is a ListView. Call `openContextMenu` with the result of `findViewById(R.id.{whatever id you want});` to get the context menu of the relevant View.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure but I think you can't open **ContextMenu** on **Back Key** because **ContextMenu** should be open on particular View.

But you can open any **Dialog** on **Back-Key** see below code

```
@Override
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK)
        {
            //Your Dialog Code
            return true;
        }
        return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

This will detect if the user has clicked the back button.

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event)
{
    // Checks if back key was clicked and if it was clicked only once
    // since multiple clicks could be configured in android for other functions
    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK && event.getRepeatCount() == 0)
    {
        // Code to open contextmenu
        return true;
    }
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
```

[This](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html) will give information on using `View.openContextMenu()`.

Answer (score 0):

Just call  [Activity.openOptionsMenu()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#openOptionsMenu%28%29) to open the menu.

```
       @Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event)
{
    switch (keyCode)
    {
    case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK :
        MyActivity.this.openOptionsMenu();
        return true;
    }

    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: Thank you, but it hasn't (I did change the activity to my own activity). The rest of my code (I added a toast message for testing on back key pressed) executes fine. The above code appears to do nothing when clicked unfortunately. My onCreateContextMenu and onContextItemSelected appear to be fine aswell. Thanks for your input

Comment: Thanks again for your help, though its the 'context menu' that pops up in the middle of the screen as opposed to an options menu coming up from the bottom of the screen. I'd typically expect the onCreateOptionsMenu to come up when 'menu' is pushed.

Answer (score -1):

Override onBackPressed Method

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
  //Your code here
}
```

Comment: Thank you, what what I mean is, how do I call the contextmenu? AFAIK the only way to call is 'registerForContextMenu()'